# The axis label at x=0 does not show up

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 to draw a line chart. The value at x=0 does not show up.

[image]

The code for the axis is shown below.

```
const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data[0].series, d => d.time))
    .range([xPadding, width - xPadding]);

const xAxis = d3
    .axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(4)
    .tickSizeOuter(0)
    .tickSizeInner(0)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y'));
```

I am not sure why it is not showing up the label at x=0, which is 2014. On checking the SVG, only three tick marks are displayed, but the one at x=0 is not in the SVG element.

CodePen for this: https://codepen.io/vijayst/pen/bLJYoK?editors=1111

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle/equivalent with dataset and complete code in order for us to easily reproduce?

Comment: @XavierGuihot Added a codepen - https://codepen.io/vijayst/pen/bLJYoK?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see different solutions which have their pros and cons. The third solution should be the cleanest and most generic.

#### Add the left tick manually:

Since d3 handles itself the location of x-axis ticks, one way of doing so would (if the data set is fixed) would be to manually add the missing tick:

```
svg 
  .append("g")
  .append("text")
  .text("2014-02-01") // can be retrieved from data instead of being harcoded
  .style("font-size", 10)
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - yPadding + 10) + ")")
```

which looks great, but in this case you might have problems if for a given dataset, d3 chooses to display a tick close to the left edge of the axis. Both d3's tick and the label we've included could overlap.

---

#### Modify the x-scale to start before the first day of the year:

An other solution would be to increase the x-axis range on the left to make it start one month before the first point's date. To try this out, we can replace:

```
.domain(d3.extent(data[0].series, d => d.time))
```

with

```
.domain(d3.extent([new Date(2013, 12), new Date(2019, 1)]))
```

which allow d3 to legitimately include a "year-tick" for 2014 at the begin of the x-axis.

but in this case, the first point will have an offset with the begin of the x-axis range.

---

#### Push a specific tick to ticks auto-generated by d3:

An other solution: we can push a specific tick to the ticks auto-generated by d3. But this requires to modify the format of ticks to "%Y-%m".

In order to do this, replace:

```
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"));
```

with

```
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m"));
```

we can then push a new specific tick to the set of ticks generated by d3:

```
var ticks = xScale.ticks();
ticks.push(new Date(2014, 1, 1));
xAxis.tickValues(ticks);
```

and include some padding in the left and the right of the chart since now tick labels have a part displayed outside the graph:

```
const svg = d3
  .select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("padding-left", 15)
  .style("padding-right", 15);
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. I dropped the time part and it works fine. Example: `moment(male.time).startOf('day').toDate()`